# Django unexpectedly splitting queryset objects on spaces

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having a problem where Django, or a form, is splitting object list items on spaces.

If the object_list is something like: `["picture"='image1.jpg "dir_as_title"='UnknownArtist', "picture"='image2.jpg' "dir_as_title"='Unknown Artist']` and I run it through the following:

```
<div>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background:url({{obj.picture}});
    background-size: 100% 100%; min-height: 260px; max-width: 480px;" >
        <form id="form" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value={{ obj.dir_as_title }}
            name={{ obj.dir_as_title }} class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The first item will be fine, displaying 'UnknownArtist' in the button, and passing 'UnknownArtist' as its input.  The second item will display the button as 'Unknown', and appears to pass no value, resubmitting its current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being embarrassingly simple.  In other areas of the template, the double-brackets around a variable suffice, such as `<h2>{{ title }}</h2>` but in the form, they must be quoted.  Using...

```
<input type="submit" value="{{ obj.dir_as_title }}" 
name="{{ obj.dir_as_title }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"/>
```

...works as expected, that is, it's no longer splitting the value.  I hope this saves someone else from all the searches I did.